# How can I remove noise in my preamplifier circuit?

Tags: noise, microphone, preamp

[image]

I need a low noise microphone preamplifier for my Arduino. I used a battery and standard wire but I had noise in my circuit. I need gain 20-20kHz.

Can you help me with the schematic?

[image]

Comment: We don't design circuits for you here. We help with problems in circuits you designed. And even if we did design circuits for you, we wouldn't be able to since you've provided no information about your microphone or anything else.

Comment: how can i remove noise ? can you suggest me ?

Comment: You haven't given us any information about your setup so we we can't tell you how to improve it.

Comment: i sent you can see in top

Comment: You should be able to place a capacitor in parallel with R3 which would bypass high frequency noise around R3 and prevent it form being amplified as much. Pick on so your cutoff is 10kHz or so with R3. I doubt your microphone works very well up to 20kHz anyways and you probably can't even hear that high. Power rail decoupling capacitors also always help.

Comment: My problem is noise

Comment: @Jason "noise" is not a very useful description. What frequency is the noise? Is it correlated to something external? Is it white noise? What nodes does it appear at? What does its spectrum look like? Use the test equipment you have on hand to provide as much detail as you are able to, in order to help narrow down the likely cause.

Comment: @Jason Your microphone part number/datasheet would be required in order to do a low noise design over some specified bandwidth you desired. Newer devices use a more complex IC. Older devices use a JFET. (That is, if this is what it looks like -- an ***electret*** microphone. If you are open to using a different microphone, that might be an even better option to consider, too.

Comment: this my electronic microphone

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=electronic+microphone&sxsrf=ALeKk014t_f6wdGIOam0JTC2Pj_4FiZ-nQ:1618521770137&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie5625l4HwAhWHasAKHdNcAtQQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1366&bih=657#imgrc=ZyQyR965nPwWJM

Comment: @Jason, if you want help then please improve your question. Put the make and part number of your microphone and the link to a datasheet into your question, not buried in the comments. Read the comments carefully and try to answer them. If English is not your first language then please add this to your user profile.

Comment: It reminds me of what one of my mentors said once: "Creating a microphone pre-amplifier is serious business. As attention in detail in design as well as the part selection as well as physical layout design will truly reveal its craftsmanship" -- Rupert Neve, 1990

Comment: You have very low gain, what do you need?

Comment: i have an analog data i wanna extract it

Comment: @Jason - When he asked what you need, he meant what sound levels you are measuring, and what voltage noise level you can accept. What is the maximum sound level you want to measure, what voltage should that be, and what is the greatest noise level you can accept? Please, "I have an analog data i wanna extract it." is of no help whatsoever. Stop talking in generalities and start giving actual requirements. Nobody here can read your mind.

Comment: @Jason - When you say, "My problem is noise ", once again you are not giving anybody any help. How much noise are you getting? What is its frequency? Is it 50 or 60 Hz (in which case it is probably power line pickup). Is it a sine wave? a square wave? Is it repetitive at all, or is it completely random in shape?

Comment: i sent you can see it top

Comment: Why does Jason not describe the noise with words?? The Audacity graph also has no words. Is the noise low frequency hum or is it high frequency hiss or is it distortion?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you have an electret mic which works like this:

[image]

I guess you built the preamp because you either tried the mic as is (some audio inputs allow it, they have the needed DC circuit) or you inserted a resistor, capacitor and DC voltage as shown in the datasheet, but the sensitivity was so low that to get acceptably high recording level one must shout if the distance is say 5 inches. Normal speech is enough if the distance is say 1...2 inches.

You feel you do not ask anything special, because you have seen for ex. in TV how the mic can be 1 meter or even more away from the talker and still it catches the voice with no audible hiss. You have seen older answers to questions which want quite the same and they all seem to give only some coarse general suggestions such as

- have a battery, computer operating voltage is not clean enough
- do not expect that uA741 or LM358 can work as ultra low noise audio preamp; forget that 50 years old crap and use some serious design with serious parts
- have a grounded metal case and shielded cables
- prevent all digital circuit supply current to go through audio circuit ground wiring
- bring all interfering radio transmitters out of the house or at least a few meters away (wifi, bluetooth, phones...)
- etc... (see NOTE1)

but none of them tell what's the right circuit - a simple clean amp, which lifts the level up but doesn't insert any audible hiss. That's what's asked. No more sophistry nor belittling comments, thank you!!!!

Let's make some elementary math. The mic sensitivity is about 44dB below 1V/Pa. That means one pascal sound pressure generates voltage about 6mV.

One pascal is a hefty level. Human speech at 1 meter distance is maybe 10 millipascals. i.e. 40dB below 1Pa. The mic outputs with that sound level 60 microvolts.

The datasheet has S/N spec. The noise level at the mic output would be 60 dB below the signal level in case the audio pressure level was 1Pa. The normal speech at 1 meter generates 40 dB below 1Pa, so the noise is only 20dB below the normal speech signal. That means 60 microvolts of speech mixed with 6 microvolts of noise. That's very audible hiss. No preamp can help because that was the noise generated inside the mic. More likely a low cost preamp can add several microvolts its own noise to the mic signal but that depends radically on used parts and design (see NOTE2) The only way to win the noise is to have louder sound. Bringing the mic to 1...2 inches away from the mouth probably is enough.

Professional recording equipment are based on more sensitive mics which have less noisy internal electronics. Of course, the preamp must be in the same league. Designing that preamp really shows who understands high quality audio electronics and who doesn't.

NOTE1: Those general comments should be taken seriously. If you do not obey them your case is hopeless.

NOTE2: This Maxim mic preamp IC is a good example of noise spec for low cost amp https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/audio/MAX9814.html

It has audio band noise voltage spectral density 30nV/sqrt(Hz). Full 20kHz audio band gets 4,2 microvolts and that's added to the mic signal. RMS geometric voltage sum with mic's noise  6uV  gives total 7,3uV (NOT 10.4 uV).

Hints for better preamp designs are useful only if one has also a better mic. Some preamp design ideas and actual circuits can be found from here: http://www.janascard.cz/PDF/Design%20of%20ultra%20low%20noise%20amplifiers.pdf

I have not built the circuits to test them, but they at least look plausible and the given explanations do the same.

Comment: I built amplifier 1.2 from the PDF and it works as described. I only changed BJT for opamp. But as is also noted in PDF, getting suitable jfets can be a major problem especially if you want hand solder friendly package.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

One of these solutions may fix it, depending on missing details of “noise”

What is noise in engineering terms?

1. In AUDACITY open Analyze PLOT SPECTRUM after selecting an audio channel. Repeat for L & R channel
2. If noise in on R channel , may we assume this is your noise?
3. Use flexible small coax for all connections.
4. add 100 R + 10uF to power circuit and keep all wires very short.
5. Connect 0V to earth ground if possible.

Comment: i sent noise level , Noise decreases when I hold the wire

Comment: Then that is line hum and poor grounds. You are a better ground. Common Mode noise issue. Follow my suggestions.

Comment: Obviously the ordinary wires are not a shielded audio cable (coax) so they pickup mains electricity hum noise and any other interference.

Comment: You should define your abbreviations

Comment: OK @ScottSeidman All of them?   uF SMPS AM and Canadian Broadcasting Corporation ( tongue in cheek noise source)

Answer (score 1):

This is so different from my previous answer that it earns to be shown differently.

Removing noise in preamp is possible with complex processing - so complex that it's no more called mic preamp. In addition it's not perfect. To avoid artifacts to the recorded audio low noise amps and sensitive mics with low self-noise are used if possible.

But let's assume you have a not so low noise mic like an ordinary $1,- electret. Using it for weak audio can easily cause S/N as low as 20 dB or less. An old school way to remove the noise is silence automatically the signal if the audio level is below a preset treshold. That's noise gating. It makes the result better only subjectively because silent periods are really silent. But audio which is not silent contains still the noise.

In 1990's everyone became able to buy audio cleaning PC software. The effect was radical - people used it to clean music recorded to hissy audio tapes. The same process is today possible in virtually real time with even low spec computer hardware. The idea is to calculate the FFT spectrum of the audio and simply kill these frequency components which are too weak to be essential. The tresholds are measured by taking at first a noise sample.